# UiTableView cell animated cells are hidden under section view.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Okay so I've added a picture of what's going on and this may help visualize the issue a little better.

[image: sectionViews]

So once I click on the "Shopping & Deals" section image a list of items or cells drop down; however, as you can see there are still some cells that are hidden under the "Shopping & Deals" image. Now here's the code:

```
- (void) sectionOpened : (NSInteger) section{

    SectionInfo *array = [self.sectionInfoArray objectAtIndex:section];
    array.open = YES;

    //Google PageView tracker
    self.trackedViewName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Find Things To Do -- %@",array.category.name];

    //Mobile Apptracking track event
    [[MobileAppTracker sharedManager] trackActionForEventIdOrName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Find Things To Do -- %@",array.category.name] eventIsId:NO];

    NSInteger count = [array.category.list count];
    NSMutableArray *indexPathToInsert = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i<count;i++)
    {
        [indexPathToInsert addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section]];
    }

    NSMutableArray *indexPathsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSInteger previousOpenIndex = self.openSectionIndex;
    if (previousOpenIndex != NSNotFound)
    {
        SectionInfo *sectionArray = [self.sectionInfoArray objectAtIndex:previousOpenIndex];
        sectionArray.open = NO;
        NSInteger counts = [sectionArray.category.list count];
        [sectionArray.sectionView toggleButtonPressed:FALSE];

        for (NSInteger i = 0; i<counts; i++)
        {
            [indexPathsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:previousOpenIndex]];
        }
    }
    UITableViewRowAnimation insertAnimation;
    UITableViewRowAnimation deleteAnimation;
    if (previousOpenIndex == NSNotFound || section < previousOpenIndex)
    {
        insertAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationTop;

        deleteAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationBottom;
    }
    else
    {
        insertAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationBottom;

        deleteAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationTop;
    }


    [atableView beginUpdates];
    [atableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathToInsert withRowAnimation:insertAnimation];
    [atableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    [atableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:deleteAnimation];
    [atableView endUpdates];

    self.openSectionIndex = section;


}
```

Now if you look at the bottom of the code there's this:

```
[atableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
```

and this offsets the view according the y bounds. The reason for this was because if you look at the picture, once I clicked on the "Productivity" section the cells would drop down past the view and you couldn't tell if any cells had actually populated, so offsetting the content pushed the view up so that those cells would appear. Now the issue is that once I click on "Shopping & Deals" the cells just kind of hang underneath the section. Does anyone have any ideas on how to tackle this one?